# Move folder retrospectively in Git

Tags: git, github, directory-structure

I forked a repository which had a strange directory structure which I fixed as follows:

Before:

> /core/src/com/example/core/Core.java
>
> /simulation/src/com/example/simulation/Main.java

After:

> /src/com/example/core/Core.java
>
> /src/com/example/simulation/Main.java

When I moved these directories around, I was completely new to Git and simply did a `git rm` on the old ones and a `git add` to the new ones.

I have since made many changes to the files and I would like to send a pull request to the original repository for the new structure and content.

**How can I tell Git to retrospectively move (mv) the files so that it is obvious where the files came from?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A `git mv filex` is the exact same as `git rm filex` followed by `git add new\location\filex`.

There is no reason you would need to retrospectively change it.

[Here](https://git.wiki.kernel.org/index.php/GitFaq#Why_does_git_not_.22track.22_renames.3F) is some more info on it

Comment: You are absolutely right. If I initiate a pull request, it seems that Github 'knows' that /orig/path/File.java -> /new/path/File.java